# How to kill a child process and not leave behind a zombie?

Tags: python, linux, process, kill

I am keyboard manager script that listens for keys and starts process in the background. This is done mainly for the sake of convenience. Let's say I press the hotkey that lunches the application below. The application lunches as a child process of the parent (the keyboard manager script). Sometimes, I get a problem with the process and I need to kill it so that I can run a new one. However, if I kill the child process, it doesn't go away and remains a zombie process of the parent. I would like to know how to kill the child process and have it go away (i.e., stop being a zombie process).

```py
if "jupyter-lab" not in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
    cmd = [ JUPYTER_PATH, "lab", "--notebook-dir=" + NOTEBOOK_PATH]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        start_new_session=True,
    )
```

Comment: You reap zombies by waiting for them.  That probably happens via `subprocess.close`, or similar.  You should probably put the Popen in a `with` clause or similar.